# Is it safe to disable commit log?

Tags: cassandra

Is it safe to disable commit log if we use replication? When a node fails it is often due to hard disk failure so in that commit log would not help us for durability but replication would. Why do we even need a commit log when we use replication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With no commit log, data stored in the memtables on the replicas may take a long time (could be unbounded, but in practice is often minutes) to be written to disk.  This means, within that window, you could lose writes.  If, for example, your data center loses power, you could lose all the writes for the last few minutes on all replicas.  The commit log syncs (by default) every 10 seconds so you would lose at most 10 seconds of data in the event of simultaneous failure.

However, if you're using multi-data center replication then to lose data you would need simultaneous failures across data centers.

It's a trade off: commit log with no replication guards against a single node crashing or having a non-destructive failure.  With replication in single DC, it guards against whole DC  failure e.g. power failure.  With replication in multi-DC, it guards against correlated failures.  You can decide how much resilience you need based on the cost of enabling the commit log versus the cost of losing recent writes.

Comment: I guess that with multi DC and RF=3 it should be safe enough to disable commit log. But how much more performance can someone gain by disabling it considering that by default it fsync every 10s?

Comment: I haven't run any benchmarks, but I would guess that if you ran two insert tests, one with durable_writes enabled and one disabled (if disabled, the commit log is bypassed for this column family), they would be much the same. However, the big advantage of no commit log is you don't need a separate disk for the commit log (which is the recommended setup) so for systems with few disks it could give a lot more I/O for data.